# ASP.NET MVC. No idea how to use Url.action to pass an object to the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I was able to create my view and display the data (Gridview). Additionally, I was able to create a hyperlink (using Url.Action) passing string and int types. However, I want to create a hyperlink that it is referencing a more complex type. The class associated with my view has a reference to a List. What I want is to create an additional ActionResult in my controller that gets as a parameter List (See below)

```
public ActionResult ViewItems(List<Items> c)
{            
    return View(c);
}
```

My idea is when is to be able to pass that List to the controller and then the controller will call the corresponding view. I tried (See below) but I just get blank.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LinkContractID" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Url.Action("ViewItems", new {c = **((Contract)Container.DataItem).ContractItems.ToList<Items>(**)}) %>'
Text='<%# Eval("ContractId") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I do not know what happened but it does not show: 
NavigateUrl='<%#Url.Action("ViewItems", new {c = ((Contract)Container.DataItem).ContractItems.ToList<Items>()}) %>'

Comment: GridView...? Isn't that a WebForms control? You shouldn't be using that with MVC.

Comment: Charlino is right. This Eval() stuff dont work with MVC either.

Answer (score 3):

Like in the previous answer, you don't use asp controls. There are pros and cons with Html.ActionLink however, it isn't so good if you want to put a link around an image for instance. In this case the syntax would be

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action(
   "ShowListPage", "MyController", new { modelId = 101 }) %>">
   <img src="img.gif" />
</a>
```

Also with your action in the controller, you would ideally be looking to have this go and get the model to pass to a view strongly typed to this model. So you have a model object with a constructor taking an id, for instance

```
public MyModel(int modelId)
{
   this.TheListThatHoldsTheGridData = MyDataLayerProc(modelId);
}
```

This way you can have your action in the MyController controller, return the view ShowListPage (associated with a MyModel instance) like so

```
public ActionResult ShowListPage(int modelId)
{
   return View(new MyModel(modelId));
}
```

Hope this helps,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a grid, [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-26-cs.aspx) shows how to create a grid with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

With MVC, you shouldn't use Gridview and asp: controls. If you want to generate a link, just use <%=Html.ActionLink(...) %> with the necessary parameters.